# How to write a function passing in Class name in Java?

Tags: java, function

I have the below piece of code.

```
    Fragment emptyViewFragment;
    Fragment songListingFragment;

    // .... and various codes ...

    if (emptyViewFragment == null) {
        emptyViewFragment =
                (EmptyViewFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(EmptyViewFragment.TAG);
        if (emptyViewFragment == null) {
            emptyViewFragment = new EmptyViewFragment();
        }
    }
    addFragment(emptyViewFragment, EmptyViewFragment.TAG);

    if (songListingFragment == null) {
        songListingFragment =
                (SongListingFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SongListingFragment.TAG);
        if (songListingFragment == null) {
            songListingFragment = new SongListingFragment();
        }
    }
    addFragment(songListingFragment, SongListingFragment.TAG);
```

The two pieces of if-else codes looks very similar, and I'm thinking of making a function from it, so that I could just make my code as as below: -

```
    EmptyViewFragment emptyViewFragment;
    SongListingFragment songListingFragment;

    // .... and various codes ...

    createFragment(emptyViewFragment, EmptyViewFragment);
    createFragment(songListingFragment, SongListingFragment);
```

or even better (since the 2nd parameter is the 1st parameter pass in object's type).

```
    EmptyViewFragment emptyViewFragment;
    SongListingFragment songListingFragment;

    // .... and various codes ...

    createFragment(emptyViewFragment);
    createFragment(songListingFragment);
```

How should my `createFragment` function be written?

Comment: Which IDE are you using? If it is Eclipse, you can use the short-cut (Alt+Shift+M) to generate a common method and later you can put additional Class parameter accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
private void a (Fragment frag, Class<? extends Fragment> clazz, String tag) {
    if (frag == null) {
        frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (frag == null) {
            try {
                frag = clazz.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    addFragment(frag);
}
```

You can access to the tag attribute inside and delete the tag parameter too

**UPDATE**

I can not test it now, but I think you can access to the static member TAG in this way

```
private void a (Fragment frag, Class<? extends Fragment> clazz) {

    try {
        if (frag == null) {

            frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(clazz.getField("TAG").get(null).toString());

            if (frag == null) {
                frag = clazz.newInstance();
            }
        }
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    addFragment(frag);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Francisco! Can I not send the TAG in, but access through the class or the object? The TAG is a final static string in the class.

Comment: frag.getClass() will throw NPE, since frag is null at this point.

Comment: Yessss. you are right. Pass the class instead, I will update the answer

Comment: Thanks Francisco, I finally ended using your first approach above, sending in the TAG directly. Tick for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the class, you can use an abstract factory:

```
Fragment createFragment(Fragment fragment, FragmentFactory factory) {
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(factory.getTag());
        if(fragment == null) {
            fragment = factory.createFragment();
        }
    }
    addFragment(fragment, factory.getTag());
}
```

Where `FragmentFactory` is an interface which will have one implementation for each fragment type.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public addFragment(Fragment frag) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Fragment newFrag = frag.getClass().newInstance();
    //...
}
```

---

This will not work if `frag == null`.

If this is your use case, then get the class by using `Class<Fragment> clz = EmptyViewFragment.class`, then call `clz.newInstance()`.

Comment: Thanks dotvav! How should I handle the TAG? TAG is a static final string variable in the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @param fragment
 * @throws IllegalAccessException 
 * @throws InstantiationException 
 */
private static void createFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag, Class<? extends Fragment> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment =
                 getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = clazz.newInstance();
        }
    }
    addFragment(fragment, tag);
}
```

Assuming that Fragment is a Parent class of other to *Fragment classes and with following method defintion :

```
    /**
 * @return
 */
private static Fragment getFragmentManager() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi Dishi, I think `fragment.getClass().newInstance();` will crash, given fragment is null.